# Permission/Timezone Errors - Drupal 6-7.x - How to resolve?

Tags: apache, drupal

I've recently been tasked with moving a client out of a shared hosting environment into an AWS environment where all the infrastructure was hosted and supplied by Amazon.  The client is running multiple (dated) Drupal instances, but luckily I've been able to move the environment over and have it function, except for the errors below.

I've discovered that Drupal is generating errors throughout their environment(s) on the AWS instance, but not on the shared hosting instance, despite using the same except code base/database.

**Permission Error(s):** https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rxaA.jpg

**Timezone Error(s):** https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F8hD.jpg

Personally, I'm not a big Drupal guy and I've researched the file permissions on the root directories (https://www.drupal.org/node/244924), but I honestly do not want to go around changing things without fully knowing the effect of a change.

If anyone can provide insight to the root of these errors and how I can potential resolve them, I would greatly appreciate it.

**P.S.** - Most of the environments in question are running on Drupal 6.33 *(not 100% sure)*, but they do have one environment running on Drupal 7.23 *(again, not 100% sure)*.

Comment: For the record, I attempted to submit this question over at Drupal.org and it appears their forum is not submitting posts properly for new users.

Comment: Looks mostly due to Drupal or PHP version issue. Can you check those version both in your shared hosting environment and AWS ?

Comment: Thanks @KannanMohan for taking the time to respond.  Please look at the commend that scronide posted below.  This was the cause and root of the issue(s) I was experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the web server's user/group owns the Drupal files, not root. Then follow the file permission instructions in [INSTALL.txt](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/INSTALL.txt/7).
2. Select a timezone in the Regional Settings of your Drupal site on AWS. If that doesn't do it, set the `date.timezone` in the `php.ini` file there.

Comment: Just so you're aware, these were the exact two things that needed to be modified to solve this issue.  I solved this issue shortly after posting this, but wanted to take the time to credit @scronide with the proper fix.